# Normalize audio data from getByteFrequencyData by volume

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I've created a `getSpectrum` method using the `getByteFrequencyData` method on the Web Audio API's Analyser Node. The array of audio data returned is relative to the audio source's (either an  el, or Audio() instance) `volume`, a value from 0 to 1.

Using the audio source's volume I'm trying to normalize each value received from getByteFrequencyData so that the user of getSpectrum doesn't have to worry about volume when they're visualizing the audio data.

This is the striped down version of getSpectrum

```
var audioData = new Uint8Array(analyser.binCount);
var spectrum = [];

analyser.getByteFrequencyData(audioData);

for (var i = 0; i < audioData.length; i++) {
  var value = audioData[i];

  //Where I'm trying to calculate the value independent of volume
  value = ((value / audioEl.volume) / 255);

  spectrum.push(value);
}

return spectrum;
```

The [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#widl-AnalyserNode-getByteFrequencyData-void-Uint8Array-array) references the equation used to calculate the returned value given a maxDecibels and minDecibels. With my rudimentary understanding, I've tried to inverse the math so I get a normalized value, but I can't getting it working exactly right. I'm having trouble accomplishing this with just a volume value from 0 to 1.

Any incite would be greatly appreciated! Heres a [working example](https://likethemammal.github.io/visualizer-micro/example.html) of the issue. Changing the volume slider will illustrate the problem.

**Update 7/22/16:** Thanks to @raymond-toy's answer I figured out how to convert the 0 to 1 volume value to decibels.

```
volumeDB = Math.abs((Math.log(volume)/Math.LN10)*20);
```

After getting the DB, I inversed the equation in the W3C spec,

```
value = ((audioDataValue * volumeDB) / 255) - volumeDB
```

Unfortunately, `value` somehow still ends up relative to `volume`. Does anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: You could get around this problem by putting a GainNode in between the `analyser` and your `context.destination`. Then you would have a volume slider that adjusted the GainNode instead of the audio's volume. This way the volume gets adjusted only after passing through your `analyser`.

Comment: For what I'm working on, I wouldn't have control of what sets the volume, so I wouldn't be able to put a GainNode in front of whatever that would be. This is a good idea tho. Will consider it for other projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I was on a fool's errand. As [@raymond-toy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162425/xyz) pointed out, Spectrum values are implicitly relative to volume. Normalizing would mean losing a portion of data "off the bottom of the spectrum", which was not my goal.

If anyone's curious, I ended up just dividing the `audioDataValue` by 255, getting a float from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 2):

`getByteFrequencyData` returns values in dB.  You don't want to divide these values by the audioE1.volume.  You want to convert (somehow!) audioE1.volume to a dB value and add (or subtract) that from values from `getByteFrequencyData`

It might be easier to understand things if you used `getFloatFrequencyData` first to see what's happening.

Comment: This was a great first step. Found the math to turn 0 to 1 volume to DBs
`Math.abs((Math.log(volume)/Math.LN10)*20)`.

Plugging that in to the inverse equation of the w3c spec didnt work either.

`value = ((audioDataValue * volumeDB) / 255) - volumeDB;`

`value` still ends up relative to the volume somehow. IDK what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I think you're better off with value = audioDataValue - volumedB.  Don't divide by volumeDB; dividing two dB values doesn't really make sense. And I don't understand why you want to normalize the spectrum.  It's not going to work right with getByteFrequency because as volume decreases, you're going to lose values off the bottom of the spectrum anyway.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Subtracting makes sense, just didn't know it worked that way. I assumed the change in audioDataValue is proportional to the volume level somehow. I'll try that out